# Bootstrap 5 - Unwanted white space at the bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have adopted Bootstrap 5 fixed navbar example in my site but after spending hours researching I'm yet unable to remove the white space at the bottom. Please see Bootstrap 5 link, and notice the bottom white space underneath the card.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/navbar-fixed/

My site has the same white space whenever the page is "brief", whereas for long pages obviously it does not appear.

I have tried overriding via my custom css file with the below but this yielded no results. I know this sheet does get picked up because I'm using for other stuff.

```
html, body, footer {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;

}


footer.well{
  margin-bottom: -20px !important;
}
```

Can anyone please shed some light as to how I can remove this white space?

Here's the code from said site:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.88.1">
    <title>Fixed top navbar example · Bootstrap v5.1</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/navbar-fixed/">

    

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/docs/5.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="navbar-top-fixed.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="container">
  <div class="bg-light p-5 rounded">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how fixed to top navbar works. As you scroll, it will remain fixed to the top of your browser’s viewport.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/docs/5.1/components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
  </div>
</main>


    <script src="/docs/5.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags.

Comment: I would guess you have some kind of `min-height` set on the body or other element. But I 'm not sure anyone will be able to solve this without seeing it live.

Comment: Thank you Schmalzy. It is live (see first link). I also looked at the body and added those overrides but still nothing! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've just copied in its entirety the example site you linked to, that has a stylesheet called 'navbar-top-fixed.css' with the following rule

```
body {
    min-height: 75rem;
    padding-top: 4.5rem;
}
```

As you can see, it has a min-height rule of 75rem. Its designed to showcase the fact that the navbar is sticking to the top when the content overflows by forcing the content to be very tall. It is not intended this would be used in actual code. If you've copied that stylesheet onto your site, you just need to remove the min-height rule (the padding rule is still important if you want the navbar as this stops the content from appearing underneath your navbar)

Comment: I think you hit the nail in the head Rob. Thanks so much!